# How to make BaseAdapter show AlertDialog android Application

Tags: java, android, listview, android-alertdialog

How can I make the button in BaseAdapter in listView shows alertDialog, I tried that but it Stopped work unexpected (RunTime Error) my code is shown below .

any suggestion

thanks in advance

Monerah

====after Update =====================

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyCasesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    private List<MyCaseClass> listOfCases;

    // TODO delete it not imp.
    public MyCasesListAdapter() {

        super();

    }

    public MyCasesListAdapter(Context context, List<MyCaseClass> listPhonebook) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listOfCases = listPhonebook;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return listOfCases.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listOfCases.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        MyCaseClass entry = listOfCases.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mypage_row, null);


        }

        // this is row items..
        // Set the onClick Listener on this button
        Button ConfExpandRegion  = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expand);
        Button Cancelb = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancelCase);
        TextView tvCase = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mypage_name);

        //To be a clickable button
        ConfExpandRegion.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        ConfExpandRegion.setFocusable(false);
       //For Dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyCasesListAdapter.this);
       alertDialog.setTitle("Conformation");
       alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to do ???");
        ConfExpandRegion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      // Some code

                       //ConfExpandRegion.setEnabled(false);
                   }

                });

                alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // here you can add functions
                    // Do nothing 




                   }
                });

                alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                alertDialog.show();




        }});

       //To be a clickable button
        Cancelb.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        Cancelb.setFocusable(false);
        Cancelb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MyCaseClass entry = (MyCaseClass) v.getTag();
                listOfCases.remove(entry);
                // listPhonebook.remove(view.getId());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        // Set the entry, so that you can capture which item was clicked and
        // then remove it
        // As an alternative, you can use the id/position of the item to capture
        // the item
        // that was clicked.
        ConfExpandRegion.setTag(entry);
        Cancelb.setTag(entry);


        // btnRemove.setId(position);


        return convertView;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        MyCaseClass entry = (MyCaseClass) view.getTag();
        listOfCases.remove(entry);
        // listPhonebook.remove(view.getId());
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    private void showDialog(MyCaseClass entry) {
        // Create and show your dialog
        // Depending on the Dialogs button clicks delete it or do nothing
    }

    public void add(MyCaseClass myCaseClass) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listOfCases.add(myCaseClass);
    }






}
```

//============================================================================

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyPage extends Activity {

    Button createForm;
    Button ConfExpandRegion, Cancelb;
    String ExpandMsg, CancelMsg;
    boolean b;
    MyCaseClass mycase;
    TextView tvCase;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mypage);


        // Moving to anther activity
        createForm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.creat_new_formbtn);
        createForm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent j = new Intent(MyPage.this, CreateNewForm.class);
                startActivity(j);

            }
        });

        // ============================================================================================
        // for list


            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mypage_list);
            list.setClickable(true);

            final List<MyCaseClass> listOfPhonebook = new ArrayList<MyCaseClass>();

            MyCasesListAdapter adapter = new MyCasesListAdapter(this, listOfPhonebook);

            for (MyCaseClass m : All_Static.getMyCaseList())
                adapter.add(new MyCaseClass(m));

            // after fill the adapter.. assign the list to the adapter
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long index) {
                    System.out.println("sadsfsf");
                ;
                }
            });
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        // ========================================================================================

    }



    public void sendSMS(String number, String msg) throws Exception {
        if (!b) {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, msg, null, null);
        }
        b = true;
    }

    // ========================================================================

}
```

Comment: Did you get this answered?

Answer (score 11):

Are you 100% sure when you pass "this" as the parameter when creating your Adapter that you are passing the Activity?

One good way to check is to modify the app like this:

*Add an Activity parameter to your adapter*

```
private Context context;
private Activity parentActivity;
...
public MyCasesListAdapter(Context context, List<MyCaseClass> listPhonebook, Activity parentActivity) {         
    this.context = context;         
    this.listOfCases = listPhonebook; 
    this.parentActivity = parentActivity;    
}
```

*Create your alert dialog like this...*

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(parentActivity);
```

*Lastly, call the contructor of your adapter like this...*

```
MyCasesListAdapter adapter = new MyCasesListAdapter(this, listOfPhonebook, MyPage.this);
```

Explanation: You probably don't need to pass in Activity and Context to your base adapter, but I did this just so you can keep everything else as is for the time being. I'm not sure if "this", when you are instantiating your adapter, is actually an activity. I defined the 3rd parameter in the constructor as "Activity" to force you to pass in an Activity. You'll get compile errors if you try and pass in something that isn't and activity, so it should help you out.

Also, I just noticed, but the problem is probably that your updated code is still trying to create the AlertDialog using MyCasesListAdapter.this as the context, which is not an activity.

Answer (score 7):

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getRootView().getContext());
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    deleteExp(tid);
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing your **alertDialog** is not even initialised.. so NPE .. and when you create it inside an Adapter make sure to use `activity context and not ApplciatioContext`

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourACtivity.this);
```

the above line should not be in the class level.. it should be inside `getView()` method... and use your activity instance as Context.. something like `nameOfYourActivity.this`

Comment: AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); I did that, there's a syntax error !!!

Comment: @Monerah ..take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292451/creating-and-showing-an-alertdialog-from-a-custom-listadapter

Comment: @Monerah .. yo man.. use Activity instance not your Adapter instance,.. What is your Activity name...?

Comment: In addition to moving the the instatiation of AlertDialog to your construction/getView, you need to also make sure that the context parameter you are passing in is an Activity. Can you show us the calling code that instatiates this adapter?

Comment: Can you post the logcat of the runtime error your getting? We probably should have asked for this a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an [`AlertDialog.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) to build an `AlertDialog`.

Comment: AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); I did that, there's a syntax error

Comment: Take a look at the sample [AlertDialogSamples.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html)